# Can't Get File Upload to Work in the Apache Solr 4.5 Administration UI Documents Screen

Tags: apache, solr

Using the Apache Solr 4.5 Administration UI core specific *Documents* tool, I have been unable to get *File Upload* working (selecting xml and pasting some xml into the *Document(s)* textbox works fine).

After clicking on the *Choose File* button, I use explorer to find one of the xml files in the exampledocs directory that comes with the Solr distribution. I then set &literal.id=doc100 for the *Extracting Req. Handler Params* textbox, Leaving *Commit Within* at 1000 and *Overwrite* as true.

After hitting the *Submit Document* button, it all seems to work (the results pane indicates success and returns a zero status), but the supposed uploaded file does not get indexed.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

So this was a commit 'problem'; the files were being indexed, but not committed, so the changes were not visible. And this seems to hold true, no matter what value I give *Commit Within*, so this feels like it may be a bug. However, the fix to making the changes visible is simply to commit the newly indexed files by running something like solr/update?commit=true

Answer (score 0):

In solr 5 I am facing the same problem. I have to commit the changes by triggering the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/update?commit=true
```